# User input as part of URL

Tags: java

I am creating a java web service which does addition function. Right now, I have set default values in my method (firstNumber is 2 and secondNumber is 2) so when I run the application (localhost), i get `{"firstNumber":2,"secondNumber":2,"sum":4}` as the output. Is it possible to make it such that user types in firstNumber and secondNumber as part of the URL and the sum is shown? How do i get the URL to be `http://localhost:8080/addition/firstNumber=2&secondNumber=2` and the sum will be shown. What should i add in AdditionController.java?

Here are my codes:

**Addition.java**

```
public class Addition {

private int firstNumber, secondNumber, sum;

public Addition(String firstNumber, String secondNumber) {
    this.firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(firstNumber.trim());
    this.secondNumber = Integer.parseInt(secondNumber.trim());
    updateSum();
}

public int getFirstNumber() {
    return firstNumber;
}

public void setFirstNumber(int firstNumber) {
    this.firstNumber = firstNumber;
    updateSum();
}

public int getSecondNumber() {
    return secondNumber;
}

public void setSecondNumber(int secondNumber) {
    this.secondNumber = secondNumber;
    updateSum();
}

public int getSum() {
    return sum;
}

public void updateSum() {
    this.sum = this.firstNumber + this.secondNumber;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Addition [firstNumber=%d, secondNumber=%d, sum=%d%n", //
            firstNumber, secondNumber, sum);
  }
}
```

**AdditionController.java**

```
@RestController
public class AdditionController {

private static final String template = " %s";

@RequestMapping("/addition")
@ResponseBody 
public Addition addition ( 
        @RequestParam(value="firstNumber", defaultValue="2") String firstNumber,
        @RequestParam(value="secondNumber", defaultValue="2") String secondNumber,
        @RequestParam(value="sum", defaultValue="2") String sum){
    return new Addition(
            (String.format(template, firstNumber)), String.format(template, secondNumber)); 
   }
 }
```

Someone please guide me through on where i should make changes. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Which errors do you get, and what kind of URL are you calling ?

Comment: Right now the URL is `http://localhost:8080/addition` and i get `{"firstNumber":2,"secondNumber":2,"sum":4}` as output

Comment: you don't want `/{sum}` in your url, because the user might not know it (I guess that's why he would call this function)

Comment: I want to get something like `http://localhost:8080/addition/firstNumber=2&secondNumber=2` then output would be the sum

Comment: @Lino yes that is correct

Comment: you're messing a lot up, you have two ways: 1) `http://localhost:8080/addition/2/2` or 2) `http://localhost:8080/addition/?firstNumber=2&secondNumber=2`. But not something in between, that's why you have to get rid of some parameters in your method...

Comment: I know, i am so confused :(

Comment: I would like to know how do i go about to getting that. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pathparam to send int1 and int2 via url and extract it at server side.       `url: http:localhost:port/appname/path/param1/param2

server end:

@GET

@Path("{param1}/{param2}")

public Response getSum(@PathParam("param1") int A,@PathParam("param2") int B)`

Comment: So do i have to get rid of all the `@RequestParam` in my set of codes?

Comment: yes, u can. @PathVariable has some placeholder from the uri   and request parameters can be optional, but path variables cannot

Comment: I get the error: `<identifier> expected
    public Response getSum (@PathParm(param1) firstNumber, @PathParam("Param2")
secondNumber)`

Comment: Pls put expected identifier/ data type like @PathParm(param1)  int firstNumber etc